# movie player not stop in table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller

in my project display video on custom cell when cell is visible the video play. automatically

```
- (void)checkVisibilityOfCell:(CustomCell *)cell inScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {

      CGRect cellRect = [aScrollView convertRect:cell.frame toView:aScrollView.superview];

      if (CGRectContainsRect(aScrollView.frame, cellRect)){
          videoPlayingCell  = (CustomCell *)cell;
          [cell notifyCompletelyVisible];
      }else{
          [cell notifyNotCompletelyVisible];
      }
}
```

in "notifyCompletelyVisible" method call when completely visible cell and custom cell video play automatically thats working ok but when  i try to go other view or tab that video playing continuously i also stop video when disappear the table view but it is playing

```
-(void)notifyCompletelyVisible
{
    NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[dictObj valueForKey:@"videourl"]];
    if([self isAlreadySeenVideo:[dictObj valueForKey:@"videourl"]])
    {
        NSURL *docUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self getVideofromDoc:[dictObj valueForKey:@"videourl"]]];
        _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:docUrl];

    } else {

        _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:aUrl];
    }
    asyvideoImage.hidden = YES;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:_moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieDidExitFullScreen:)                                                  name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification                                                object:_moviePlayer];

    _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    _moviePlayer.view.frame = asyvideoImage.frame;
    _moviePlayer.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [self.contentView insertSubview:_moviePlayer.view belowSubview:tvImageView];
     [_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
     [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(pauseVideo:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];


 }
```

and my notifyNotCompletelyVisible method is

```
 -(void)notifyNotCompletelyVisible;
 {
      [_moviePlayer stop];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieDidExitFullScreen:)                                                  name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification                                                object:_moviePlayer];
}
```

so how to stop video when i go to another view or tab

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just create one instance of your movie player in the `UIViewController` that you need, and make sure that instance is destructed when there's a navigation to another VC or tab.

Comment: but video view in custom cell so that all kind of programming i done in custom cell and call when cell is visible if cell is not visible then i release all that object as well as stop the video.

Comment: Well, try to use the delegate methods of the class, rather than your own methods, so that they're handled in a better way during navigation to/from them. I think `viewDidLoad` method will be helpful for you, depending on when you want to play the video. Read the documentations about `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, etc.